# Android PopupWindow button disappears after click

Tags: android, popupwindow, onclicklistener

I'm having a very frustrating problem with **PopupWindow** on Android. 
I've implemented my own class that inherits **PopupWindow** and implements 
**OnClickListener**.

After adding button backgrounds with custom selectors problems start. 
This background keeps disappearing after clicking the button (starting new activity and dismissing the popup). 
It doesn't disappear after "*focus and click*", only after "*quick click*".

Any idea/suggestion would be very appriciated!

```
public class TestPopup extends PopupWindow implements OnClickListener

protected LayoutInflater inflater;
protected Activity caller;
protected View popup;
protected View layout;

public TestPopup(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    popup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) caller.findViewById(R.id.contentLayout));
    layout = popup.findViewById(R.id.layout);

    popup.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    Display display = caller.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    setHeight(display.getHeight());
    setWidth(display.getWidth());
    setFocusable(true);
    setContentView(popup);

    // fix to allow Popup to be clickable!
    setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    popup.setOnClickListener(this);
    popup.findViewById(R.id.addButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    popup.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton).setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = null;
    if (v.getId() == R.id.addButton) {
        intent = new Intent(caller, AddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AddActivity.ACTION_ADD, true);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.deleteButton) {
        intent = new Intent(caller, AddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AddActivity.ACTION_DELETE, true);
    }

    if (intent != null) {
        caller.startActivity(intent);
    }

    TestPopup.this.dismiss();
}
```

[image: Popup]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to call **popup.invalidate();** before dismissing the popup.

Comment: That's solved my similar problem as well, but that remove animation which i need... :(